# Data communication in power harvesting project

Tags: communication, low-power, energy-harvesting

I want to design a wearable gadget for elderly to detect falling. This gadget should work by energy harvesting. Now I want to find the best effitient way of power consumtion to send data to a station for emergency alert. Does anyone have any experience to help me choose the best way to communicate? I myself think about ultra-low power bluetooth module but I don't know the best ultra-low power bloutooth module. Can anyone help me? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: With long term battery powered or energy harvesting the most important thing to consider is the constant energy consumption. In your case, how to reliably detect a fall.  The RF TX part is easy since it's such a low duty cycle (one time).

Comment: How much power do you think you can harvest? How much energy will you have stored when it is time to make a transmission? You are asking only about the best way to communicate, so I assume you have worked out these other critical details.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Thanks for your reply. I haven't test anything yet, But according to an article, I think I can harvest bout hundreds of micro-Watts power and 1.1uJ energy per day from the kinetic energy of user. I don't know how to relate these numbers to different part of the device such as the sensor, microcontroller, and other parts. Would you please explain it for me?